# What volume of water will dilute an acidic solution back to neutral?

Tags: acid-base

Now we are talking about simple dilution, not acid-base neutralization, so we expect asymptotic behavior that never quite gets us back to pH=7; that is, an infinite amount of water would be required. However, most pH probes read to two decimal places, so diluting to reach pH=6.995 is a sufficient end condition. So, given an initial pH of $pH_0$ and an initial solution volume $V_0$, what additional volume $V$ of pure water would be required to dilute the pH to 7.00 (6.995)?

I've wondered this for a while, and today I attempted to solve it. I may have found the solution, but I am skeptical of its implications. If I have 1 L of a solution at pH=2, my derived formula indicates it would require additional volume of about 8.6 million liters of water for the solution to read neutral. Is this reasonable?

My derived formula:

$$V=\Big(\frac{1}{1-10^{-0.005}}\Big)\Big(10^{6.995-pH_0}-1\Big)V_0 \\
\approx \Big(86.36\cdot10^{7-pH_0}-87.36\Big)V_0$$

**Derivation:**

Moles of $H^+$ from original soln: $n_0 = [H^+]_0V_0$

from added water: $n = [10^{-7}]V$ (via autodissociation)

Total moles: $n'=n_0+n$

Total volume: $V'=V_0+V$

New molarity after addition of $V H_2O$:

$$[H^+]'=\frac{n'}{V'}=\frac{[H^+]_0V_0+[10^{-7}]V}{V_0+V}$$

$$\Rightarrow V=\Big(\frac{[H^+]_0-[H^+]'}{[H^+]'-[10^{-7}]}\Big)V_0$$

(Note that $V \to \infty$ as $[H^+]' \to 10^{-7}M$, an infinite volume is require to exactly reach neutral pH).

Letting $[H^+]'=10^{-6.995}M$ (paragraph 1), $[H^+]_0=10^{-pH_0}$, and multiplying top and bottom by $10^{6.995}$, obtain:

$$V=\Big(\frac{10^{6.995-pH_0}-1}{1-10^{-0.005}}\Big)V_0$$

**Question:** Is this derivation valid? Are there assumptions I should or should not have made? Would it truly take 8.6 million times the original volume to dilute a pH=2 solution back to neutral pH=7.00?

Comment: Since water establishes an equilibrium with $\ce{OH^-}$ as well as with $\ce{H^+}$, I don't think you can leave that out when considering what happens in the system as you add water.

Answer (score 3):

The very *idea* of diluting a solution back to (almost) neutral with pure water is unreasonable, precisely because it would require insane amounts of water. That being said, your derivation (though impractical) is not meaningless; it is just slightly wrong.

Like **J. Ari** said in the comments, there is an equilibrium involving $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$, and it will be shifted by the dissolved acid (that is, the concentrations will shift so the equilibrium constant may stay the same). Therefore you can't assume that water will *always* contain precisely $10^{-7}$M protons from autodissociation (plus maybe some extra from acid). It doesn't work that way.

How does it work, then?

$$\ce{[H+]\cdot[OH-]=10^{-14}}\\
\ce{[H+]-[OH-]=}c(\rm{HCl})$$
(since the acid is strong, and hence fully ionized even in not-so-diluted solutions)
$$\ce{[H+]=10^{-6.995}}\\
\ce{[OH-]=10^{-7.005}}\\
c\ce{(HCl)=10^{-6.995}-10^{-7.005}=10^{-6.995}(1-10^{-0.01})}\\
V_{total}=V_0\cdot{c_0\over c}\\
V_{added}=V_0\cdot\left({c_0\over c}-1\right)
=V_0\cdot\left({10^{6.995-pH_0}\over1-10^{-0.01}}-1\right)$$
So it is *only* 4.3 million times the original volume, which is about 2 times less than your estimate.

Not that it made much of a difference, really.